# Cloud storage for files that shouldn't be changed

Tags: backup, cloud-storage

I have more than 5 Terabytes of video files. Currently stored on a Synology NAS. I want to backup to the cloud.

However, video storage is not a natural fit to neither "cloud disk" (Google Drive) systems or "cloud backup" systems (CrashPlan) because:

- Data is written once and rarely used.
- There are no file revisions.
- Delete should be prohibited.
- Modifications (viruses, ransom-ware) should be prohibited.

So, my question is: **Could you recommend a cloud storage service for write once, read only files, specifically one working well with Synology Cloud Sync?**

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Comment: Hi Izzy. Not to be nitty about it, I would assume that each such service comes together with a client utility...

Please also note that this question also raised issues in Information Security and in Super User. There HAS to be a place on Stack Exchange where one CAN ask such a question.

Comment: That's why I didn't close your question straight away (didn't want to be nitty either ;). But essentially, you're asking where to host your files – and that the service should also have/provide matching software. I leave the final vote to the community (being a mod here, my vote would be binding immediately). If it needs discussion, there's always our Meta site ;) Until then, let's agree on "border line", shall we?

Comment: I think what's interesting about this question is that it is about a need that is not immediately obvious. Had I been asking about which cloud storage solution is cheaper, I would not argue. However, I'm asking if there is a solution for storage of immutable files. This is new.

Again, not (really) arguing. Border line it is :)

Comment: Agreed. Leaving these comments stay for now, so potential close-voters can balance both sides of the medal before deciding to drop something ;) Good luck then!

Comment: Amazon Glacier is targeted to write once, read seldom. But that's all I know, you'll have to investigate further.

Comment: @JanDoggen THANK YOU!!! May not be the solution I need but the concept of Cloud Archiving is probably enough to get going. Why don't you post it as an answer so I can mark it?